# How to center the navigation?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to customize a navigation of a Wordpress-theme.

I have tried everything but the navigation is just not centering. I have tried it with `text-align: center; display: inline; display: inline-block.` And even with `margin: 0 auto;` Nothing seems to work.

Maybe I'm applying the rules at wrong place?

I am thankful for any help.

Here is the HTML-code:

```
    <div class="menu_main">
        <div class="navbar yamm navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-toggle .navbar-collapse .pull-right " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span>Menu</span>
                    <button type="button"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">
                <nav id="navigation">
                    <div class="menu-top-navigation-container">
                        <ul id="king-mainmenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-18 yam-fwr"><a href="http://www.brodreneskogen.no/om-oss/">OM OSS</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-19 yam-fwr"><a href="#">VAREUTVALG</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-20 yam-fwr"><a href="http://www.brodreneskogen.no/historie/">HISTORIE</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-21 yam-fwr"><a href="#">VINBLOGG</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-22 yam-fwr"><a href="http://www.brodreneskogen.no/kontakt/">KONTAKT</a></li>
                            <li id="menu-item-209" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-209 yam-fwr"><a href="#">TEST 1</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .menu_main{
        float: none !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        z-index: 9999;
    }

.navbar-default{
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.navbar{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-header{
    float: left;
}

div#navbar-collapse-1.navbar-collapse.collapse.pull-right{
    z-index: 10000 !important;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse{
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important
}

.pull-right{
    float: right !important;
}

nav#navigation{
    text-align: center;
}

nav{
    display: block;
}

.menu-top-navigation-container{
    float: none !important; 
    text-align: center !important;
}

.navbar-nav{
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    width: 90% !important;
}

.nav>li{
    display: inline !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: You are showing us the coloring book but not the crayons you are using. Without the CSS, we cannot help.

Comment: Please provide css for this.

Comment: This looks like it's based on Bootstrap..so the first thing would be to remove the floats

Comment: @Rob I have updated the question with CSS-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove float form `ul` and `li`  and `text-center` class `navbar-collapse`

```css
CSS:
.navbar-nav{
       float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav > li {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <div class="menu_main">
            <div class="navbar yamm navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <div class="navbar-toggle navbar-collapse pull-right " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span>Menu</span>
                        <button type="button"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse text-center">
                    <nav id="navigation">
                        <div class="menu-top-navigation-container">
                            <ul id="king-mainmenu" class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-18 yam-fwr"><a href="http://www.brodreneskogen.no/om-oss/">OM OSS</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-19 yam-fwr"><a href="#">VAREUTVALG</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-20 yam-fwr"><a href="http://www.brodreneskogen.no/historie/">HISTORIE</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-21 yam-fwr"><a href="#">VINBLOGG</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-22 yam-fwr"><a href="http://www.brodreneskogen.no/kontakt/">KONTAKT</a></li>
                                <li id="menu-item-209" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom dropdown menu-item-209 yam-fwr"><a href="#">TEST 1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u look if another rule don't overwrite your rules?

Maybe you can try to put `!important` to your rules to see if this work. Like this: `text-align: center !important;`. It will takes priority on other rules.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: I looked the reputation system, it say we need to have voted up answer or posting questions. I won't post questions just to have reputation, so how I do? If people don't give enough informations i have to wait people to ask for more informations, but i won't rest on this post all the day to way for that :/ For me it seems to be the only solution.

Comment: If you don't have the reputation you just have to NOT comment until you have earned enough.

Answer (score 0):

First delete `pull-right` from `div#navbar-collapse-1`, then:

```
.menu-top-navigation-container{
   text-align:center;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
ul.king-mainmenu {text-align:center;  display: table;  float: none; margin: 0 auto;}
```

`ul.king-mainmenu > li { display: inline; float:left; }`

`.menu_main { float:left;width:100%;}`

Comment: This did not work for me I'm afraid. Thanks for your help!